# Show/hide mantaflow particles

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

This is probably a simple answer, but I can't seem to find it.

I've already searched BSE, but I can't find a related question.

How can I show/hide the *particles* in the mantaflow simulation? I would like it so that I can only see the baked mesh, not the particles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your domain. Go to the particle properties tab. Change "Render As" to "None"

Comment: Thanks. I also found that disabling the particles viewport view button in the modifiers tab works as well.